# How to make c# project to compile and watch with Rollup?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, vue.js, msbuild, rollup

I have VS project on `ASP.NET Core 2.0` server side and `Vue.js` on client side.
I bundle and compile Vue.js files using `Rollup`.

I want in my VisualStudio to make bundle and watch by `Rollup` on compile.

I use this code in `MyProject.csproj`

```
<Target Name="DebugRunRollup" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Exec Command="rollup -c --environment NODE_ENV:dev" />
</Target>
```

And all work perfectly, it compile js files on build.
But I also need to watch them.
Trying this code, but it did not work, no compile now,no watch.

```
<Exec Command="rollup -c -w --environment NODE_ENV:dev" />
```

How to make VisualStudio project to compile and watch with rollup.

I want when I update client code to update it in browser, without recompiling full project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to avoid having client-side tasks run during the server-side build process. This just couples those two sides although you are usually developing them quite individually.

Instead, I would suggest you to add a pre-publish step within the `.csproj` that just runs your client-side build *once*, so you can publish your application including the built client-side code. That could look like this:

```
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="rollup -c" />
</Target>
```

And then, you should consider having your client-side build process with its watcher run when you are opening the project in Visual Studio. That way, as soon as you start working on the project, you get a freshly compiled app and whenever you make changes to the client-side scripts, you can rely on your client-side build process to update the files properly.

You can make scripts automatically run when you open the project by using the Task Runner Explorer. If you are using a build tool like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), then support is already built-in. Otherwise, you can also install the [NPM Task Runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner) to pick up scripts from your `package.json`.

The tasks will then appear in the task runner window, and you can start them from there or bind them to the “Project Open” event for example to make them run automatically:

[image: Task Runner Explorer with tasks from the Gulpfile and the package.json]

If you are using Visual Studio Code, then the client-side build tasks are also picked up by default, and you can use an extension like [Blade Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yukidoi.blade-runner) to automatically run these tasks when you open your project in Code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using JetBrains Rider, but project file was created by VisualStudio Community with `ASP.NET Core React template`. And there was `HotModuleReplacement` with `Webpack`. But I desided to switch my project to `Rollup` It was running in project by `app.UseWebpackMiddleware` in `sturtup.cs`. But there is no function like `UseRollupMiddleware`.

Comment: I’m not using Rider but it surely has a similar concept of launch tasks too. At least [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Installing_and_Removing_External_Software_Using_Node_Package_Manager.html#d65559e512) [do mention](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Tools_Startup_Tasks.html) something in that direction.

Comment: Thanks, so I will follow your suggestions, and find this functionality on Rider.

Comment: As for that middleware, it’s certainly not required to be able to do client-side development. I think it’s just mostly for a deep integration with Webpack itself (to ease the development with hot reloading where changes are pushed to the browser directly etc.). If you are not dependent on that, then you won’t need it for Vue with Rollup.